# Getting Debian to send email to a real address

Tags: exim

I'm running Debian on an old computer on my home network to do stuff like netatalk, dlna,...

I have a number of programmes I've written myself that can send e-mail using the credentials for my regular e-mail.

I've set up `/etc/aliases` so that all mail goes to `root`, but it would be better if it could go to my real e-mail address -- like my programmes do?

Is this possible?

I suppose I could write a programme to check `root`'s mail, forward it, and delete it. But that seems like a bit of a crap workaround.

I see that something called `exim` is installed, but this seems to be for computers that have a domain name and are going to be SMTP servers themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can bravely configure `exim` or `postfix` or even `sendmail` to do this. But there are several so called "simple" MTA: `msmtp`, `ssmtp` and probably there are others, which are designed exactly for this purpose: to allow server to send mails as all software would expect, yet without blowing out the complete general purpose MTA.

Also you need a real mail server and an account there, for example, Gmail will do the work. Configure the simple MTA (according to manuals) and voila.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use a script/tool for sending mail from the command line. something like this: https://github.com/mogaal/sendemail

with a tool like that you can use an external smtp server (like those from your ISP) to send out mail.

Comment: I don't think [mogaal/sendemail](https://github.com/mogaal/sendemail) project is still active/updated, I'd advise against using that and move to something else, e.g. [msmtp](https://marlam.de/msmtp/download/).